# Error:SqlTransaction has completed

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

**Code :**

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in grdListKala.Rows)
            {

                if (grdListKala.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        objCon.Connecting();
                        objCon.con.Open();
                        transaction=objCon.con.BeginTransaction();
                        //******************************************
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
                        cmd1.Connection = objCon.con;
                        cmd1.Transaction = transaction;
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //******************

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row2 in grdListKala.Rows)
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                            cmd2.Connection = objCon.con;
                            cmd2.Transaction = transaction;
                            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
                            cmd3.Connection = objCon.con;
                            cmd3.Transaction = transaction;
                            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        }
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exp)
                    {
                        if (transaction != null)
                            transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        objCon.con.Close();
                        transaction.Dispose();

                    }
```

**Error :** 
This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
i tried the cmd object's close befor transaction.commit because already error in connection that was open !
how can i use this three command text in transaction without error !

Comment: You are closing the connection with `cmd1.Connection.Close();` and expecting the transaction to stay valid?

Comment: For the record, some `using` statements would be **much** clearer (and harder to get wrong) than `try`/`catch`/`finally`

Comment: Error Happens for line : transaction.Rollback();

Comment: @Amin yes, same will be on `commit`. See my answer for a better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL transaction is valid for a connection. Once you close the connection you are then either committing or rolling back that transaction. Keep the connection open for the life of the transaction. Essentially you need to do this:

```
open connection
    start transaction
    command 1
    command 2
    ...
    command n
    commit transaction
close connection
```

Comment: it's return new Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object? this happens for 'null transaction'.

Comment: i just remove cmd1.Connection.Close();cmd2.Connection.Close();cmd3.Connection.Close();

Comment: @Amin And all of the (now redundant) `Open` calls?

Comment: @Amin `cmd1.Connection.Open();` for example.

Comment: I need to see the full code now, too many potential changes to keep track of.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Unless you are missing some lines, it is working fine. What is the exact error message and on which line does it occur?

Comment: Error is : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in line transaction.Commit(); ? this meen the object of transaction is null !

Comment: That means either the line `transaction=objCon.con.BeginTransaction();` is not giving you a `transaction` object or somewhere you are setting it to `null`. Nothing else can interfere with that object other than your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening and closing your connection way too often:

```
objCon.con.Open();
...
cmd1.Connection = objCon.con;
cmd1.Connection.Open();
```

The second `Open` isn't needed, and neither is the `Close` after your `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Basically, you're trying to reopen the connection before executing each command, then closing it again afterwards.

You're also closing the connection once in the `catch` clause, then again in the `finally` clause.

Just get rid of all the `Open`s except the very first and all the `Close`s except the very last.